Passing params to lambda.Code.fromInline(code)
I have this code:
const someVar = "some value";
const rewriteFunction = new cf.experimental.EdgeFunction(
            this,
            "RewriteFunction",
            {
                runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
                handler: "index.handler",
                code: Code.fromInline(`
                exports.handler = async (event) => {
                    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
                    //I want to access someVar here
                };
                `),
            }
        );

How can I access someVar inside the dynamic code passed to fromInline()?

You can use template literals, const str = \Access ${someVar}`;`

@hoangdv seems so obvious now. Thanks!
